# GROUP result set BY column provided an element in group has different column with specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If I had a table as shown below and I want to find the max date for each ID, provided at least one of the elements of the ID group has an Info value of 1. So ID 2 would not be included since both of the elements with ID of 2 have an Info value of 2. ID 1 and 3 are included because those ID fields do have at least 1 element with Info value of 1.

```
ID        Date       Info
---------------------------
1      01-01-2013     1
1      02-02-2013     2
1      03-03-2013     2
2      01-01-2013     2
2      04-04-2013     2
3      01-01-2013     3
3      05-05-2013     1
3      06-06-2013     1
```

So output would look like this.

```
ID      MaxDate   
-----------------
1      03-03-2013     
3      06-06-2013
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [EXISTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) predicate to check that a record where info = 1 exists for the given ID

```
SELECT  T.ID, MaxDate = MAX(T.Date)
FROM    T
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    T T2
            WHERE   T2.ID = T.ID
            AND     T2.Info = 1
        )
GROUP BY T.ID;
```

You can achieve the same thing with a conditional aggregate in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT  T.ID, MaxDate = MAX(T.Date)
FROM    T
GROUP BY T.ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN T.Info = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you. Using the HAVING clause was the solution I used. It gives me a lot of flexibility for further filtering of the the INFO column. I tried it before but didn't use the case statement within the HAVING clause.

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
Select id, max(date)
From my_table
where id in (select id from my_table where info = 1)
group by id
```